# Why my function are not available after compiling the dll on matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, matlab-compiler

Function not found after compilation of a shared library on matlab

I want to use a c# program to call matlab to execute complex functions, display plots, and do algorithms.

In this goal, I start with the base, to generate matlab functions for simple things. I want to have a list of functions on matlab that are callable via my c sharp code.

What I do:

in a utils.m file:

```
function ports = getPortComs()
    ports = seriallist();
end
```

Following that i use  mcc -W 'dotnet:MatlabLib,MatlabClass' -T link:lib utils.m to generate dll file.

On Visual Studio 2022, i add reference to this dll.

My C# code :

```
using MatlabLib;

namespace XXX
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MatlabClass matlab = new MatlabClass();

            string[] ports = matlab.getPortComs(); //HERE : Not found
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Not used yet
        
        }

        
    }
}
```

On comment //HERE : Not found, i can't found this function.
Error is : "Error CS1061 'MatlabClass' contains no definition for 'getPortComs' and no extension method "

Do you have any idea where the problem lies or any suggestions for me?

Comment: If you put a function definition in a file called `utils.m`, then the function is called `utils`. The name after the `function` keyword is ignored in this case. Pay attention to the warnings that the MATLAB Editor gives you.

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible to have a list of functions in a utils.m file and manage a dll? 
I was also under the impression that if I wrapped functions in a UtilClass, it had the same effect. Is there any way to do this without creating multiple .m files?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don’t want to create multiple M-files? This is just the way MATLAB works. Esch M-file defines one function. You can have more functions in the file, but they’ll be private sub-functions to the main function. You could write a single function whose first argument is the name of the sub-function you want to invoke. But it’s so much easier to write separate M-files…